# How to change line-wrap length on Drupal 6 Blog?

Tags: nodes

I'm currently managing a Drupal 6 website which has a blog displaying about 155 characters per line. I'd like to set that to under 85 if possible. Is this buried somewhere in the menus or it is something I'm going to have to find in some php file?

Comment: You won't find it in a menu or in php, you just use CSS to control something like that

Answer (score -1):

hi you can use the module [maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength) to achieve it, it can be used to set the charecter limit to any of the cck field like body, summary, title etc.